# move to main activity failed

Tags: android

i have here the code for my splash screen but it seems to be wrong when i put my splash screen on my program when going to the main game, anyone can help? thanks!

here's my code:

```
        public class SpalshScreenActivity extends Activity {
         public void onAttachedToWindow() {
                super.onAttachedToWindow();
                Window window = getWindow();
                window.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
            }


        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.splash);
            StartAnimations();

        }

        private void StartAnimations() {
            Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.alpha);
            anim.reset();
            LinearLayout l=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lin_lay);
            l.clearAnimation();
            l.startAnimation(anim);

            anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate);
            anim.reset();
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
            iv.clearAnimation();
            iv.startAnimation(anim);

            anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translatez);
            anim.reset();
            ImageView ib = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo2);
            ib.clearAnimation();
            ib.startAnimation(anim);}

            protected Class<? extends Activity> getFollowUpActivity() {
                return BodyPartsGameActivity.class;
            }
    }
```

Comment: your question is not clear !!

Comment: " it seems to be wrong " can you precise ?

Comment: im sorry, i mean when i start the application, it stops in the splash screen and does not continue to the main game which is my game menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is "why does it not progress from splash screen to the next activity".... you never give a command to do that. Why do you think that having a getFollowUpActivity on a normal Activity does ever get called?

you need a specialized Activity or use a thread to forward your splasscreen to the main screen after a specific time.

Comment: For AndEngine, you need to extend "BaseSplashActivity" to make it work and override the getSplashDuration() to set the duration.

Comment: can you give me example of specialized activity or thread, thanks.

Comment: here is a sample with a thread: https://github.com/krohling/AndroidSplashScreenExample and this is one for AndEngine: http://speilglatt.wordpress.com/2011/05/30/sort-of-a-hello-world-creating-a-splash-screen-with-andengine/